# Javascript add delay to animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate, delay

I've been trying to add a delay to one of my JavaScript animations and all I get is an error that says
"Object doesn't support property or method 'delay'". I'm testing this on IE 8 compatibility by the way.

Below is the mentioned code that I've tried.

from

`$('a',$(this)).stop().animate({'marginTop':'200'},1000);`

to

`$('a',$(this)).stop().delay(1000).animate({'marginTop':'200'},1000);`

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7hxv3kd4/JsFiddle).

Best Regards,

Vernon

Comment: what is to be delayed??... the calendar in the fiddle??

Comment: Yes, i forgot to mention, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main problems on your fiddle:

1) The animation code is set up before jQuery. Thats why you get a `TypeError: $ is not defined` in console. Include jQuery in the `<head>` before your code and without any wrapping function:

```
<head>
    ....
    <script>
        /* jQuery here */
    </script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            /* your code here */
        });
    </script>
    ....
</head>
```

2) You are using a very old jQuery version1.3.2 having no delay function. That's why you get an `TypeError: undefined is not a function` when calling `.delay()`.
Either use a newer version of jQuery (>= 1.4.3) or define the delay-function by yourself:

```
$(function() {
    // original $.fn.delay copied from jQuery v1.4.3 source:
    jQuery.fn.delay = function( time, type ) {
        time = jQuery.fx ? jQuery.fx.speeds[time] || time : time;
        type = type || "fx";
        return this.queue( type, function() {
            var elem = this;
            setTimeout(function() {
                jQuery.dequeue( elem, type );
            }, time );
        });
    };
    /* Your code here now works with .delay() */
});
```

Updated [FIDDLE here](http://jsfiddle.net/7hxv3kd4/15/) with a delay of 1500 inserted.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Defining the delay-function above my animations did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$(function(){$('a','body').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).delay(1000).animate({marginTop:'200px'},1000);
    })
});
```

SEE Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7hxv3kd4/2/

Comment: unfortunately no, I just realised that jsfiddle doesnt show the animations properly, basically when i mouse over the calendar, it slides up, and when mouse away, it slides back down, the delay is for the sliding back down, so it'll wait a second before sliding back down.

Comment: you want the animation on `mouse` `click` or `over` and `out` events?... When should the animation happen and when not?

Answer (score 0):

I have made two following changes in the code,

1. Replaced `</br> to <br/>`
2. Added `Jquery library` to the Frameworks & Extensions section of JSFiddle

I believe it works fine, Please refer: http://jsfiddle.net/7hxv3kd4/3/

Comment: What if JSFiddle get's shutdown for 2-3 days, or maybe it deletes anonymous fiddles, this answer will be incomplete and will not help anyone else anymore. Maybe you want to include what you main did. Please change your answer.

Comment: That's why I have mentioned all the changes that I have done in the list. Let me know if the answer is misleading.

Comment: What plugin did you use and why?

Comment: Apologies, it is actually Jquery library & I have added it because there seems to be many undefined errors in the console related to Jquery functions.